# Very slow loading of MySQL DB-backup

Tags: mysql, backup, mysqldump

I'm working on a transition of a web-site, which uses MySQL database as a backend.

The transition involves copying the production database -- into another *on the same server*. We do this by taking a backup into a file (with `mysqldump`), then loading it into the new DB. Nothing out of the ordinary here.

The problem is, though it takes under a minute to create the dump, loading it into a newly-created DB takes about **30 hours**.

The server is reasonably beefy and uses <s>SSD</s> magnetic drives. While the loading is running, I can see `mysqld` process becoming quite busy *initially*, using up to 100% CPU, then dropping to 3-4%. Running `iostat 1` shows writes of well under 1Mb/s, indiscernible from regular filesystem activity on a non-idle system.

The relevant section of `~/.my.cnf` reads:

```
[mysqldump]
extended-insert=false
lock-tables=false
single-transaction=false
```

The way backups are taken, the table-creation statements in the backup look like:

```sql
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `acl_groups`;
/*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = utf8 */;
CREATE TABLE `acl_groups` (
  `group_id` mediumint(8) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `forum_id` mediumint(8) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `auth_option_id` mediumint(8) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `auth_role_id` mediumint(8) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `auth_setting` tinyint(2) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  KEY `group_id` (`group_id`),
  KEY `auth_opt_id` (`auth_option_id`),
  KEY `auth_role_id` (`auth_role_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;

--
-- Dumping data for table `acl_groups`
--

LOCK TABLES `acl_groups` WRITE;
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `acl_groups` DISABLE KEYS */;
INSERT INTO `acl_groups` VALUES (2092,26,1,0,1);
...
```

If I run the loading `mysql` command with `-v` flag, I can see -- after the initial *very fast* progress -- it beginning to crawl through each `INSERT INTO` line at the rate of only about 1-2 per second...

With "keys" disabled before loading each table, why does it become *this* slow?

Comment: On the same server you can simpkly dump it directly into the database no need for the file

Comment: Sounds like there are too many indexes.  Or too small a value of `innodb_buffer_pool_size`.  Or Engine issues.  How much RAM?

Comment: The import might be executed in a single transaction.  See if you can split the dump and import one piece at a time.

Comment: @RickJames, the server has 32GB of RAM, 2 of them completely _free_, and 25 used for cache/buffers thus also available.

Comment: Increasing `innodb_buffer_pool_size` to 20G might speed up the import.

Comment: @RickJames, the value was set 1G, so I raised it to 7G for starters. I also increased the `innodb_buffer_pool_instances` from 1 to 2. The reload was still running 14 hours later, when I killed it. I need to push it down to under an hour -- do you think, 20G will help, or should I check some other parameter(s)?

Comment: Please provide the `CREATE TABLE` for it -- including all indexes.  Peek at the dump -- do the `INSERT` statements have only one row each?  Or do they have hundreds of rows per `INSERT`?

Comment: The setting `extended-insert=false` creates "hundreds of rows per `INSERT`", yes. Are you suggestings, this, is what turnes minutes into hours? Also, I notice, that the `DISABLE KEYS` lines are commented-out in the dump. Perhaps, I should try enabling them?

Comment: You write that the speed of INSERT operations drops to 1-2 per second. As an experiment, try importing only the schema (use --no-data). And then perform the INSERT operation manually, and note how long they will be executed.